# How to get ID3 Lyrics tag from MP3 file using Mp3agic jar Android studio?

Tags: android, tags, id3, mp3agic

I need to get the lyrics from mp3 song

```
Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File(file);
       
if (mp3file.hasId3v2Tag()) {

   ID3v2 id3v2Tag = mp3file.getId3v2Tag();
   Log.d("Lyrics",id3v2Tag.getLyrics());
}
```

The above code only I'm using. But its returning "java.lang.NullPointerException". Please help me to solve this issue.

The full crash report

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.example.mp3tag, PID: 10237
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.example.mp3tag/in.example.mp3tag.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2904)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1671)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6784)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:852)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:320)
at in.example.mp3tag.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:200)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2857)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1671) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6784) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:852)

Comment: Can you share your entire crash report? Where are you getting NullPointerException?

Comment: @Will thank you for your help, as you asked, the crash report added please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an exception because `id3v2Tag.getLyrics()` returned `null` and you're using `Log.d(String tag, String msg)`. See documentation regarding this method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#d(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

> public static int d (String tag, String msg)
> ... String: The message you would like logged. **This value cannot be null**.

If you want to use `Log.d` with possible null objects, use `Log.d(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)`. See documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#d(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)).

So `id3v2Tag.getLyrics()` returns `null`. The library you're using offers little documentation but I'm assuming `getLyrics()` returns `null` in the absence of lyrics, and not an empty string. This may not be an issue for the rest of your code if you test the result of `getLyrics()` properly, like so:

```
String lyrics = id3v2Tag.getLyrics();
if (lyrics != null) {
  // Lyrics found, add your code here
} else {
  // No lyrics
}
```

Comment: Yeah tried with checking null. But the mp3 which I'm using having lyrics in it. I could able to check that in online. But here it's returning NULL, I couldn't understand the problem. Please help

Comment: If your song has lyrics and `getLyrics()` returns `null`, then the problem comes either from your song file, or from the library if it fails to fetch the lyrics. But at least you know why your app crashes. Test your app with another file, or try another library.